# Autofill Spring map with values, whitch declared in other xml declarations

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

I have such bean declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans SYSTEM "../schemas/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
   <import resource="container-*.xml" />
   <bean id="containerCodeStore" class="com.mycompany.ntd.crm.xxx2.container.InMemoryContainerCodeStore">
        <property name="containers">
            <map>
                <entry key="WORKER-ONE" value-ref="workerOneContainer" />
                <entry key="WORKER-TWO" value-ref="workerTwoContainer" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

where beans `workerOneContainer` and `workerTwoContainer` declared in `container-worker-one.xml` and `container-worker-two.xml` something like this:

```
<bean id="workerOneContainer" class="com.mycompany.ntd.crm.xxx.container.workerone.WorkerOneContainer">
    <property name="name" value="WORKER-ONE" />
    ...
</bean>
```

Now it is necessary to reduce map declaration, so containers put into map itself - due to it own declaration.
In other words needs to spread map declaration out into containers bean declaration.

Comment: Do you expect Spring to put the beans into the Map automatically ?

Comment: Yes. I think it is possible.

Comment: You can autowire the two beans viz. `workerOneContainer` & `workerTwoContainer` as separate fields but not into a single map as key / value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly, I've made such changes:

1. Into the bean cofiguration `id="containerCodeStore"` added `autowire="byType"` parameter;
2. Into class `InMemoryContainerCodeStore` added field `List<WorkerContainerParent> containerList`. Now this list filled with containers automatically by Spring;
3. Also into class `InMemoryContainerCodeStore` added `afterPropertiesSet()` method, which to populate map `containers` from `containerList`.

And it is allow me to removed all entries from `<map>...</map>` because map filled automatically.